# SqlBulkCopy not importing data from Excel

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I'm doing a simple project exporting data from Excel to SQL Server with Visual Studio 12 and C#. I managed to import from Excel to a DataSet, but not insert them into my database, although the code is showing a positive message box that I've set to tell me when it is OK.

It's saying that my data was successfully exported to SQL, but when I choose "show table data" no data is shown; the table is empty. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace testoledb    
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      DataSet OleDs = new DataSet();
      OleDbDataAdapter OleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {    
      }

      private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
      {
      }

      private void upload_excl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
         path = Path.Combine(path, "AGENDA.xlsx");
         string path2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
         path2 = Path.Combine(path2, "Database1.mdf");

         string OleConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+path+@";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;MDR=Yes;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0'"; //,HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""";

         OleDbConnection OleConn = new OleDbConnection(OleConnectionString);    
         string OleStrCmd = "select * from [Feuil1$A1:I330]";    
         OleDbCommand OleCmd = new OleDbCommand(OleStrCmd, OleConn);

         try
         {
            OleConn.Open();
            OleDs.Clear();
            OleAdapter.SelectCommand = OleCmd;
            OleAdapter.Fill(OleDs);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = OleDs.Tables[0];

            //***************************************charger la base*******************************************************************************
            using (DbDataReader dr = OleCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
               // SQL Server Connection String
               string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + path2 + ";Integrated Security=True";

               // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
               using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
               {
                  bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[Table]";
                  bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                  MessageBox.Show("Data Exoprted To Sql Server Succefully");
               }
            }
                //***********************************************************************************************

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());    
         }
         finally
         {
            OleConn.Close();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you HAVE to import the data this way?  If not, you should be able to do it very easy using `BULK INSERT`

Comment: And is your `Table` really called `Table`?

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but are you sure the data isn't being imported? As in, you've checked in SSMS and it's not being? I only ask since it sounds like you have written a UI for retrieving the table records, and I want to make sure there's no risk of the bug being on that end of things.

Comment: I would also love to see a better title on this question, just by the way. You'd be more likely to attract an answer if you had one.

Comment: @dub stylee : no i am a beginner i just find it this way so i tried if        there is another please take me to a good ref. thank you^^.

Comment: and my table is called Table.

Comment: @ matthew : well except the message that say that they are exported successfully i don't have any other mean to be sure at least i didn't wrote one

Comment: and for the title since i am not sure what is the problem i couldn't give a good one i agree with you though.  thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell if you are really importing the data, you could do something like this:

```
OleDBCommand commandRowCount = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " +
            "dbo.Table;",
            OleConn);
long countStart = System.Convert.ToInt32(
            commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());
```

That will give you the # of rows to begin with, probably 0.  Then AFTER importing the data, this:

```
// Perform a final count on the destination  
// table to see how many rows were added. 
long countEnd = System.Convert.ToInt32(
            commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());
```

That will give you the ending # of rows.  Then you can tell how many rows were imported by calculating `countEnd - countStart`.  It might also be helpful to check the value of `OleDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count` as well, to make sure there are rows in your `DataSet`.

More information about `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets(v=vs.110).aspx

**EDIT:**

I am looking back over your original code, and it looks like you do not need to use the `DbDataReader`.  Since you already have the data loaded into your `DataSet`, there is a version of `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` that takes a `DataTable` as the argument, so you could try this:

```
       // SQL Server Connection String
       string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + path2 + ";Integrated Security=True";

       // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
       using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
       {
          bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[Table]";
          bulkCopy.WriteToServer(OleDs.Tables[0]);
          MessageBox.Show("Data Exoprted To Sql Server Succefully");
       }
```

Notice, I did not include the outer `using` block with the `DbDataReader`.  Give that a try and see if that works for you.

Comment: hello, dub stylee please i already told you there is nothing in the database table quote :
                      "It's saying that my data was successfully exported to SQL, but when I choose "show table data" no data is shown; the table is empty. This is my code:"

Comment: i have rows on my dataset but not in the table Table... help please there is no exception showing that i am doing anything wrong

Comment: Could you post your table's definition?  It may be that the columns do not match the source columns from your spreadsheet perhaps.

Comment: they are copy/past names :( is there any other way to make it happen not with the bulk method please help me

Comment: @user3820191, check my edit, I added a (hopefully) more simplified way to write your data, let me know if that works.

Comment: unfortunately every thing work great but no data in the database all though i have only this database so no risk of confusion plus the log file change size when i change the number of data selected in the Sql query "Select * from [Feuil1$A1:I330]" i change it like from A1 to I27 and the log file "Database1_log.idf" changed size from 1 mo to 730k ... i am tired all the other solution requires csv files and i cant get csv to conserve the utf8 encrypting because i have arabic and french characters ... or Buisnes intelligence solution but its really not obvious that it will work ... help :( !!!

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like you are adding rows to your database, maybe with no values.  How are you viewing the database after you import the data?  Can you put a breakpoint in your code, and look at what the contents of `OleDs.Tables[0]` are before the `WriteToServer()`?  It is difficult to help without you giving more information.

Comment: i found finally a sub tiny logiciel called sql server import / export wizard and i did the transaction